# how to change docker default group

Tags: docker

Docker is running but attempts to use it (via aws sam) fail, asking if docker is running.

My ubuntu 18.04 machine gets users/groups from a windows AD (using pbis) and though I've added my self to the locally defined docker group (prepending my username with the "\", restarting (and rebooting) I cannot get the docker group in the output of "groups".

h009357:~$ grep u0138 /etc/group
docker:x:136:ec2-user,hci\u0138544

h009357:~$ groups
domain^users hci hcibldg hcimail metaframe^users bioinfouserssrvs hch-phonelistread camplab vpnusers data-exchange^dfs^access hci^rs^conference^read^only

So I'm hoping for one of two things: 
1. a way to configure docker to use an existing user group.
2. a way to get pbis to recognize the local groups definitions

Answer (score 0):

turns out I missed the "newgrp docker" directive